# Channel API - sometimes I don't get message

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I noticed that every createchannel() replaces the iFrame url.

Is there any chance that due to a re-call to createChannel() my iFrame is being replaced by new iFrame BUT the binding between the clientID and the iFrame url wasn't updated?

For example:
I called "channel.create_channel(unique_id)" - and I got back the JS with 123.talkgadget.google....as an iFrame.
Then, 
I called again with the same client id "channel.create_channel(unique_id)" - and I got back the JS with 456.talkgadget.google....as an iFrame.

Is there any chance that if I call now "channel.send_message(unique_id,msg)"
the message will be sent to  123.talkgadget.google instead of 456.talkgadget.google resulting that I didn't get the message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain about this answer.  I haven't tested thoroughly, it's a little hard to test since the dev_appserver behavior is quite different from the real server behavior.

I believe I have seen this behavior before (missing messages).

If you close the old channel from the client side it seems to make everything work properly.

I have not tried handling the case where you lose your internet connection and you can't close from the client side though.

Comment: thank you. 
what do you mean to close the old channel?

    var iframe = document.getElementById('wcs-iframe');
     if(iframe != null)
  {// alert('--');
   iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  }
  socket.close();
Doesn't help...

Comment: I meant just calling socket.close(), you shouldn't need to touch the iframe.

Comment: Is it randomly dropping messages, or does it stop receiving messages after a certain point?  I stop receiving messages if I open two channels.  If I explicitly close the first one before I open the second one, then everything works fine.